Pass international phone format while updating phone number with Quickbase Restful API
I need to pass phone numbers from a third party app to Quickbase via the Restful API.  We receive phone numbers from outside the United States, so I need to pass in the country format as well as the phone number.
After all my research, it seems like you can only change the country format through the Quickbase user interface.  However, if there is a way to not have users do double the work, that would be ideal.

You can update this property using the Fields API
{
  "properties": {
    "useI18NFormat": true
  }
}

Will reflect as this change in the UI Field Settings:

Then when you use the Records API to add/update a phone number, include the country code in the string value you pass in the Records API to add or update a record, and the country will be reflected when the user in the application.
  "data": [
    {
      "18": {
        "value": "+52-111-222-3333"
      }
    }
  ]



Thank you for that clarification!  That said, it only applies to the field in general, correct? If I wanted to pass in a phone number value from Mexico (as an example), is there a spot to pass in the country code for Mexico and apply it to the field value?
At this point, we set the "International" checkbox to True.  However, when the phone number is passed in via REST, they still have to go in and manually set the phone number to the intended country.

If the "International" checkbox ix checked, you can include the country code in the string value you pass in the Records API to add or update a record, and the country will be reflected when the user in the application.  I updated the answer with an example for the payload and a screen shot of how the data appears in the application
